# Recursive function for get complete path without siblings

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a input like:

```
var query = {"a":{"b":{"branchs":[{"$or":{"d":10}},{"$or":{"e":10}}],"f":22}}};
```

and I need a ouput:

```
output[0] = {"a":{"b":{"$or":{"d":10},"f":22}}}  
output[1] = {"a":{"b":{"$or":{"e":10},"f":22}}}
```

I need "split and duplicate" array in "branchs" keys. The object is multidimensional and it can have N branchs keys nested, so I think it should be a recursive function.

I have done several tests but I can not. I would appreciate any help

**EDIT:**
function in http://jsfiddle.net/cjsb7j1r/ (it needs a refactoring)

Comment: How do we get to know the name of properties which come alongside `"branchs"` properties inside the same object? Is this always the case that there's only one property (like `"f"` in your example)? IOW, you gave different names for nodes at each level of your query tree, thus how are we supposed to generalise the pattern? Will it always be single letter names in lexicographic order? Could it be any name (but 1 property only, and `branchs` excepted)?

Comment: And please avoid providing the code as a jsfiddle link only, put your code in the question body as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, something like this?

```
var query = {"a":{"b":{"branchs":[{"$or":{"d":10}},{"$or":{"e":10}}],"f":22}}};

//output[0] = {"a":{"b":{"$or":{"d":10},"f":22}}}  
//output[1] = {"a":{"b":{"$or":{"e":10},"f":22}}}

var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < query.a.b.branchs.length; i++){
    output.push({
       "a":{
           "b": {"$or": query.a.b.branchs[i]["$or"], "f": query.a.b.f}
       }
    });
}
console.log(output);
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8zsrwbLq/1/

EDIT: Just made a small correction since the `"f"` is always on the `"b"` level

Comment: The output is correct, but it is not valid for other input´s structure

Comment: @egimenez would you please share an example of the "other" structure?

Comment: I meant that although the result is correct, if I modify nesting or labels the function is no longer valid. I managed to perform the function, I edit the main post. Thanks!

Comment: @egimenez sure, if you change the labels or nesting structure then the functuon will most likely fail since it expects defined labels and structure.